# How to replace the deployURL value in angular.json for single spa

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am in process of migrating my angular app to single SPA. As part of the migration, I need to specify the deployURL property for each environment in my angular.json. I am using Jenkins to separately build for each environment, is there a way to pass the deploy URL as part of build process I tried below script and it did not work. I know for latest angular it has to be migrated to BASE_HREF for now I need it to be working with deployURL. I need the deployURL to different for each environment build.

```
ng build --configuration=dev --deploy-url https://mydev.app.com/" //Not working

            "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4200/" //For local
            "deployUrl": "http://mydev.app.com/" //For Dev
            "deployUrl": "http://prod.app.com/" //For Prod



 "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
          "libraryName": "my-app",
          "libraryTarget": "umd"
        },
        "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4200/"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have environment.ts and environment.prod.ts in angular ,when you use ng build it replaces environment.ts with environment.prod.ts . In your case add scripts in angular.json for each environment

```
// environment.ts

export const environment= {
 production : false,
 serverUrl : 'http://localhost:4200'
}



// environment.prod.ts

export const environment {
 production : true,
 serverUrl : 'http://prod.app.com/'
}

// environment.dev.ts
export const environment {
 production : false,
 serverUrl : 'http://dev.app.com/'
}
```